# Errors on cross-compiling Ubuntu to Centos GLIBCXX

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, centos7

I've searched for quite a bit without any solutions to this question, so I thought I'd drop it here.

I have source which compiles very well on Ubuntu and I would like to use it on my Centos 7 machine.  For the sake of this question, let's assume that compiling the code on Centos is completely out of the question.

Every time that I go to run my application, I get an error saying "'GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by....)".  When searching through my Centos' libstdc++.so.6, I can see that it only goes to GLIBCXX_3.4.19.

How can I compile my code on Ubuntu using the libstdc++.so version that stops at 3.4.19, such that I can easily run it on Centos 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to build with an older compiler and accompanying libstdc++, at least as old as the GCC version shipped with CentOS.

The alternative is to link libgcc and libstdc++ statically,  although chances are you will run into the same issues with glibc, and that cannot be linked statically. That being said, glibc might well ruin this alternative.

The only "proper" way to be 100% sure is either compiling on a CentOS host or have a sysroot replicate their base system layout.

Another more formal alternative is using the [Linux LSB compiler][1], which pretty much gives you the baseline any self-respecting Linux distro is compatible with. I don't know the extent of this compatibility though, so I can't share any experience with LSB, I only know of its existence and purpose.

[1] https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/en/Developers/LSB_Tutorial